# ¿Como Puedo mostrar el Valor de un Formulario Reactivo en una Grid en Angular/Ionic?

Tags: angular, angularjs, ionic, programación-móvil, ionic-framework

Estoy Creando una aplicacion en Ionic utilizando Angular y tengo el siguiente Formulario

```
this.CalcLecheForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      cedula:['', [Validators.required]],
      propietario:['',[Validators.required]],
      finca:['',[Validators.required]],
      latitud:[this.lat],
      longitud:[this.lon],
      altitud:[,[Validators.required]],
      extension:[,[Validators.required]],
      emisiones_co2_totales: [this.co2_eq_totales]
    })
```

Como puedo hacer para mostrar lo que contenga emisiones_co2_totales en la siguiente grid al darle clic al darle a un botón calcular?

```
<ion-grid fixed class="grillasalida">
           <ion-row> 
            <ion-col size="6" size-sm>Parametro</ion-col>
            <ion-col size="3" size-sm>Valor</ion-col>
            <ion-col size="3" size-sm>Medida</ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
            <ion-col size="6" size-sm>Emisiones de CO2-eq totales</ion-col>
            <ion-col size="3" size-sm> (Aqui iria el valor de emisiones_co2_totales )</ion-col>
            <ion-col size="3" size-sm>kg CO2-eq/año</ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="6">
              <ion-fab-button fablimpiar data-desc="Cancelar" (click)="CancelCalc()" [disabled]="!CalcLecheForm.enabled">
                <ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
              </ion-fab-button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="6">
              <ion-fab-button fabguardar (click)="Calc()" data-desc="Calcular" [disabled]="!CalcLecheForm.valid">
                <ion-icon name="save"></ion-icon>
              </ion-fab-button>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
```

Agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes llamar al formulario como una instancia de clase, que a su vez tiene la función `get()`:

```html
 <ion-col size="6" size-sm>Emisiones de CO2-eq totales</ion-col>
            <ion-col size="3" size-sm> {{CalcLecheForm .get('emisiones_co2_totales').value}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col size="3" size-sm>kg CO2-eq/año</ion-col>
```

Comment: Excelente Muchas Gracias